# Не работает ActionBar-PullToRefresh с RecyclerView

Tags: android, actionbar, recyclerview, pulltorefresh

Использую [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). Не работает Swype.

*layout*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewArticle"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_admob">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Java*:

```
mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
        .allChildrenArePullable()
        .listener(this)
        .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

Со `ScrollView` все работает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [семплах](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/samples/stock/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/samples/stock/ListViewActivity.java#L69) для списка еще используется метод `.insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)` вы уверены, что вам он не нужен?
Так же, для `.theseChildrenArePullable()` указываются аргументы - идинтификаторы списка и пустого списка.

```
ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())                        
                    .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
                    .theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list, android.R.id.empty)
                    .listener(this)
                    .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

В любом случае, если есть сэмпл, который работает, то заставить работать вашу реализацию не должно представлять проблемы.

Я, со своей стороны считаю, что разумнее использовать инструменты SDK, если они есть и обладают аналогичной функциональностью - [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)